# Android How to send text with accents to PHP

Tags: java, android, diacritics

I have a problem with my app, when i try to send a text to my apache server which contains characters like má mé mí mó mú it sent the character as m?. How can i solve that?

This is my code:

```
public boolean loginstatus(String reporte, String user) {
            File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
            try {
                  MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                  Log.e("enviando", "archivo "+fileUri.getPath());
                  Log.e("enviando", "reporte "+reporte);
                  Log.e("enviando", "usuario "+user);
                  entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                  entity.addTextBody("reporte", reporte);
                  entity.addTextBody("usuarioID",user);
                  if (file.length() <= 0){
                  }else{
                  entity.addPart("archivo", new FileBody(file));
                  }
                  final HttpEntity yourEntity = entity.build();
                  httppost.setEntity(yourEntity);
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return true;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the problem here is your encoding.
Either the database's table is not encoded to use UTF-8 or the String you send isnt.

table issue:

you can use `CHARACTER SET utf8` on your db table.

String issue:
The elegant way to solve it is using

`StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(Yourtext, "UTF-8");`

The other way is to use your String's  `getBytes("UTF-8")`  function and use DataOutputStream

Comment: Thanks, but where to put that? Thanks again.

Comment: Where ever you put your special chars. My guess is:
entity.addTextBody("reporte", reporte);
should be:
entity.addTextBody(URLEncoder.encode("reporte má mé mí mó mú", "UTF-8"), reporte);

I've found out it's easier to use URLEncoder.